# C include lib fail

Tags: c, gcc, linker, undefined-reference

I'm new to C and I want to try [this](https://ccodearchive.net/info/json.html) json de/serializer. As it doesn't need any dependence I've just put the code in a subdir of my project.

```
/
    json_test.c
    json/
        json.c
        json.h
```

Source of `json_test.c`:

```
#include "json/json.h"
int main() {
    JsonNode *json = json_mkobject();
}
```

And a part of the `json/json.h`:

```
JsonNode *json_mkobject(void);
```

The problem is that I can't use any function from the lib because the compilation fail (I think it's the linker):

```
$ gcc json_test.c -o json_test
/tmp/cco4ZDh0.o: in function « main »:
json_test.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to « json_mkobject »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm on it since yesterday, have you got any suggestion to make it work ?

Comment: A header file only typically contains function *declarations*, symbolic constants in the form of macros, and structure definitions. Including a header file doesn't automatically link with a library, or cause the compiler front-end program to build with a similarly named source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compile `json/json.c` as well:

```
gcc json/json.c json_test.c -I json -o json_test
```

Comment: @JulienCastiaux If this answer solved your problem, you may also want to accept it as an answer so that others with a similar problem can benefit from it.